# How to add a css class on a "form_row" in twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to know how I can add a css class on a "{{ form_row() }}" in twig. For the moment, I have this code :

```
{{ form_row(form.username, {'label' : "Login", 'attr': {'class': 'loginForm'}}) }}
```

... But the CSS class "loginForm" isn't used in the HTML code.

Thank you :) !

Comment: You can use form_widget as a work around.  Seems like it should work with form_row but I have not looked into it.

Comment: I was looking to use 'label' and 'attr" in the same form_row. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want the common class for the form_row (it means one class for form_label, form_widget and form_errors), you should customize a field_row block.

This article explains how to customize form fields: [How to customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html). 
There are some methods to do this.

For example I'm using Method 2 ([How to customize Form Rendering: Method 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template)):

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set class='' %}
    {% if attr.class is defined %}
    {% set class = 'class="' ~ attr.class ~ '"' %}
    {% endif %}

    <div {{ class }} >
        {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```

Comment: It might be worth noting, you may have to use {{ class|raw }} for this to work without it trying to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, and you'd better check the `row_attr` option (since Symfony 4.3).

Comment: @Dam Fa, check the date if this answer before downvote ;)

Comment: In 2021, accepted answer should be Dam Fa's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64628031/9770656

Answer (score 4):

My answer is very similar to nni6's but it allows you to pass through the entire attr array.

My HTML structure is for Twitter Bootstrap but you can have whatever you want. This example also places an error class on the wrapper div if there are any errors - this part is not required but is useful if you use Bootstrap:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set field_row_classes = ['control-group'] %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {% set field_row_classes = field_row_classes|merge(['error']) %}    
    {% endif %}

    <div class="{{ field_row_classes|join(' ') }}">
        {{ form_label(form, label|default(null)) }}
        <div class="controls">
            {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr' : attr|default({}) }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {% if help is defined %}
                <p class="help-block">{{ help }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```

The difference here is that I'm calling `form_widget` with the `attr` array (if it was specified, defaults to {})

Now you can set up your form as normal but pass through a custom class:

```
{{ form_row(myentity.myproperty, { 'label' : 'mylabel', 'attr' : { 'class' : 'myclass' }}) }}
```

Answer (score 3):

**This post need an update !**

Since Symfony 4.3, the `row_attr` option permits to add attributes (and so, some class). Let's check those links :

- Here :
  https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-more-form-improvements#row-attributes-in-form-themes
- or more specifically : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#row-attr

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to configure bootstrap in symfony

```
{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="control-group {% if errors|length > 0 %}error{% endif %}">
        {{ form_label(form, label, { 'attr': { 'class': 'control-label' } }) }}
        <div class="controls">
            {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr' : attr|default({}) }) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this without overwriting blocks is this:

```
{% set attr = {'class' : form.myElement.vars.attr.class ~ ' addedClasses...', 'style' : form.myElement.vars.attr.style ~ '; addedStyles...'} %}
{{- form_row(form.myElement, {'attr' : attr}) -}}
```